# Can I use Breeze.js with ASP.NET Web API that has MongoDB as a data storage solution

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I was trying to find out, if it is possible to use the following stack of technologies together:

- MongoDB
- ASP.NET Web Api
- Breeze.js
- Knockout.js

I've used Breeze with the Entity Framework and SQL Server, but now I would like to use it with MongoDB, since we are planning to use it for data storage. I know that there is a C# driver to be used, so using it in a Web Api is no problem. But how can I make Breeze.js to work with such API Controllers?

I found some instructions, discussion, and a sample of using MongoDB with Express and Node.js (http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mongodb), but I was unable to locate a sample with Web Api and C#.

Thank you for any advice.

UPDATE:

I found a NoDB Sample (http://www.breezejs.com/samples/nodb) that seems like a solution. I just need to manually configure entities in JavaScript, instead of fetching the metadata from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zza sample is the closest to what you want: http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza

It shows breeze, angular with node/Express/MongoDb on the server.

We do not have a sample that shows .NET/WebApi/MongoDb on the server.  This is possible but would require translating a OData query expression into mongoDb query syntax, something that we've done in node but not yet in .NET.  Please add this request to the Breeze User Voice if it sounds interesting.